# Enable DATA Api for Amazon Aurora

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

We have a running AWS Aurora Cluster (Not the serverless version).
I was already successfully connected to the DB externally via Querious (GUI for SQL)
When using the Golang RDS SDK I get the following error message:

*HttpEndpoint is not enabled for cluster sample-db-cluster. Please refer to https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/data-api.html#data-api.troubleshooting*

This links tells me to activate the Data API.

Problem: This link and anything else I have found so far always relates to serverless Aurora and I could not find any way to enable this for my Aurora instance.

I also tried to enable the DATA Api via the CLI:

```
aws rds modify-db-cluster --db-cluster-identifier my-cluster-id --enable-http-endpoint --region us-east-1
```

This did not work!

Below is my go code to connect to Aurora:

```
package main

import (
"fmt"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/credentials"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/session"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/rdsdataservice"
    "log"
    "os"
)

func main() {

    sess:= getSession()
    SQLStatement := `SELECT * FROM testTable`
    fmt.Println("SQLStatement",SQLStatement)
    rdsdataservice_client := rdsdataservice.New(sess)
    req, resp := rdsdataservice_client.ExecuteStatementRequest(&rdsdataservice.ExecuteStatementInput{
        Database:    aws.String("my-database-name"),
        ResourceArn: aws.String("arn:aws:rds:us-east-1:XXXXXXXXXXX:cluster:XXXXXXXX"),
        SecretArn:   aws.String("arn:aws:secretsmanager:us-east-1:XXXXXXXXXXX:secret:XXXXXXXX"),
        Sql:         aws.String(SQLStatement),
    })

    err1 := req.Send()
    if err1 == nil {
        fmt.Println("Response:", resp)
    } else {
        fmt.Println("error:", err1) // Produces the mentioned error
    }
}


func getSession() *session.Session {

    var sess *session.Session
    var err error
    if os.Getenv("aws_access_key_id") != "" && os.Getenv("aws_secret_access_key") != "" && os.Getenv("aws_region") != "" { // explicit credentials
        creds := credentials.NewStaticCredentials(os.Getenv("aws_access_key_id"), os.Getenv("aws_secret_access_key"), "")
        sess, err = session.NewSession(&aws.Config{
            Region:      aws.String("us-east-1"),
            Credentials: creds,
        })
        if err != nil {
            log.Println("Error cred")
        }
    } else {
        sess = session.Must(session.NewSession()) // credentials are passed implicit by role lambda-news-parser-executor (defined in IAM)
    }
    return sess
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok! I found that issue
the *github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/rdsdataservice* is only usable for serverless Aurora not the "normal" instances.

[Link here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/rdsdataservice/)

> Package rdsdataservice provides the client and types for making API requests to AWS RDS DataService.
> Amazon RDS provides an HTTP endpoint to run SQL statements on an **Amazon Aurora Serverless DB cluster**. To run these statements, you work with the Data Service API.

Answer (score 5):

> I could not find any way to enable this for my Aurora instance

This is because it is **not supported**. Data API is only for Serverless Aurora.

Comment: Okay! But if this is true, why do I receive an error message like this?

Comment: @Silicium Don't know why the message says what it says. The fact is that data api is only for serverless aurora, regardless of the error message.